# Correlation between complex random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation

I am struggling to find the correlation between two complex r.vs; **X** and 1/**Y** i.e. E{**X*/Y**}, where '*' denotes the conjugation operator. The complex r.s **X** and **Y** are correlated with each other with known covariance matrix. Moreover, E{**X/Y**} is also known.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Complex numbers are inherently two-dimensional, so you will have a set of numbers, not just one. A good "real valued" analog is the multivariate gaussian. In essense, what you are tyring to do is similar to getting a correlation between two vectors of two variables each, whcih partition the dimentions of a 4-dimensional gaussian distribution.

The complex case is a litte more nuanced because the real and complex parts of each "complex number" must bear a certain relationship to each other.

This [paper](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece461/handouts/notes6.pdf) will help you a great deal.

Comment: Link unfortunately broken - anyone know the title of the paper it is supposed to link to?